# UITableViewController Rows scrolls behind the Header cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with Headers and Rows. When the Rows scroll up into the Header section it looks like they scroll behind the Header. This is fine except I want both my Header and Rows to have non opaque alpha. The design is translucent. When this is the case you can see the Row scroll behind the Header which is bad. Ideally the row just disappears when it scrolls into the Header section.

Anyone have a solution that will still allow me to use translucent Headers? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the transparancy is making this a really tricky thing to solve.

Example image if people do not understand the question completely:
http://postimg.org/image/r60uw9o99/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

If you only have one header the easy solution I did was to just **take the header label out of the tableview** and put it in the parent view of the uitableview and just shift the uitableview to compensate for the new header view. Now make the header view transparent and the rows don't scroll behind the header view because it is in a different. The downside is that when you scroll up the header doesn't float above the next cell and obviously it doesn't work for multiple headers. Hope this helps.